# No result for scored labels in Azure ML Web Service

Tags: machine-learning, regression, azure-ml, excel

I am trying to predict scored labels using regression. But when I am about to get the result from Azure ML Web Service in Excel 2016, there is no result appeared in the scored label column. How should I fix this? Below is all my process...

[image]

Here is my problem I always get. As you are seeing now, there is no result in scored label column when I try to predict.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test out the web service in the web client under configure to see if it works ... 
There might be something wrong with the client.